# PHP 5.3.4 possible bug in round() function using PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN mode

Tags: php, rounding

Unless I have misunderstood how round() function works in PHP, I think there is a bug in it:

Example:

Running:

```
$prod = 201.6 * 0.000275;  
echo "No Round..: " . $prod;  
echo "With Round: " . round($prod, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

PHP Returns:

```
No Round..: 0.05544  
With Round: 0.06
```

What I expect:
With Round, I expected 0.05 as a result. Is this expected result right?

Enviroment:
PHP 5.3.4 running on Windows 7 64bits with Apache 2.2.17.

Tnks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

That is the correct expected result.

`PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` only comes into play when the value is exactly at half, for your case that would be 0.055.

Anything more than 0.055, eg. 0.0550000001, would result in 0.06.

If you prefer to round down, you should try `floor()`.

```
<?php
$prod = 201.6 * 0.000275;

$prod = floor($prod * 100)/100;

echo $prod; // gives 0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because PHP doesn't track overflows.

For example, try also

```
print (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

You would expect that the expression returns 8, but prints **7** instead.
This happens because the result of simple arithmetic expression is stored internally as **7.999999** instead **8** and when PHP casts the number to int it simply truncate the fractional part. It means a 12,5% error!

Use [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension instead if you need precise calculations.

Check out the *Zend PHP 5 Certification Study Guide* (php|architect) at the chapter "PHP Basics".

Comment: you're right about float numbers, but thats not the problem here: take a look at uzyns explanation to see why the result is correct and user1544649 missunderstood how `round` works.